# workbox-webpack-plugin service worker does not fetch from cache when online

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have a SW that is working fine on localhost, but does not fetch from cache online. As usual it was working fine, but somehow it stopped.

Files are cached but requests always go to the network. I have checked the files on dev tools.

I am also not sure about the cache expiration set up.

You can see it online [at this site:](https://www.soeezauto.ma)

Here is the relevant code:

registerServiceWorker.js

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
  window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
  window.location.hostname.match(
    /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
  )
);

export default function register() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      return;
    }
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const swUrl = `/dist/sw-dist.js`;

    if (isLocalhost) {
      checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
        console.log(
          'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
            'worker.'
        );
      });
    } else {
      registerValidSW(swUrl);
    }
  });
}
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
navigator.serviceWorker
  .register(swUrl)
  .then(registration => {
    registration.onupdatefound = () => {
      const installingWorker = registration.installing;
      installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
        if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
          registration.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true});
          if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
            console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
          } else {
            console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
          }
        }
      };
    };
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error);
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
  });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
fetch(swUrl)
  .then(response => {
    if (
      response.status === 404 ||
      response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
    ) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
        registration.unregister().then(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
    } else {
      // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
      registerValidSW(swUrl);
    }
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log(
      'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
    );
  });
}

export function unregister() {
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
    registration.unregister();
  });
}
}
```

The distribution code for the service worker is below. You may see the online version using cacheFirst strategy, as I tried both.

```
importScripts("precache-manifest.1d6e1c2332794b82f85bd1c2e608d2b6.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.3/workbox-sw.js");


workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/dist/img/*'),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'img-cache',
    plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxAgeSeconds: 360 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        }),
    ],
  })
);
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/dist*'),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'js-cache',
    plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        }),
    ],
  })
);
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/dist/css*'),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'css-cache',
    plugins: [
        new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxAgeSeconds: 10 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong on many accounts on this. The files were not being fetched from cache even on localhost. I was misreading Firefox's dev tools network tab. It should clearly show files are sourced by "service worker" when things work properly.

The issue was where the service worker script was placed. It should be at root.

This is the webpack.config.js that accomplished that ( Webpack 4 ):

```
 const path = require('path');
 const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
 const dist = 'dist';
 const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
mode: "production",
entry: {
    home:'./src/entry_home.js',
    rest:'./src/entry_rest.js',
    mini:'./src/entry_mini.js',
},
output: {
    //path: path.resolve(__dirname, dist),
    path: __dirname+'/dist',
    //filename: "[name].[chunkhash].soeez.js",
    filename: "[name].0211.js",
    publicPath: "/dist/"
},
externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
},
module: {
    rules: [
     //{ test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]},
    //{ test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
        }
    },
    ]
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                name: 'common',
                chunks: 'initial',
                minChunks: 2
            }
        }
    }
},
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([
        dist + '/*.js'
        ]),
    //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    new InjectManifest({
        swSrc: './src/sw_src.js',
        swDest: '../sw-dist.0211.js',
    }),
]
```

};

Comment: What does your sw_src.js look like?